# convert hibernate query to criteria for all record

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using the below code for update using query. But I want to change it into criteria. How can I change to criteria. Which is faster query or criteria?

```
Query query=getSession().createQuery("update Chat set isRead='1' where merchant.id=:merchantId and customerMobile=:mobile");
        query.setLong("merchantId", merchantId);
        query.setString("mobile", mobile);
        query.setParameter("mobile", mobile);
        int modifications=query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: AFAIK, criteria queries can't do updates. Only selects. And both are as fast: the time it takes to generate the SQL query is negligible compared to the time it taks to execute it. BTW, why would you want to transform a perfectly simple, readable and static JPQL query into a messy, unreadable criteria query?